# Oracle query works in Toad Developer but not in .net application

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012

This query works in Toad developer but not(wont return results) in an .net application in visual studio. Any clues why?
The query work if I omit the line -- having sum(total_cust_cnt) >= NVL (:customers_out, 100)

```
select   d.region_nbr, pi.city, d.case_id, c.cause_desc cause, sum(total_cust_cnt) customers, d.total_duration_minutes   
from     t_om_cause_of_trouble c, 
         t_om_archive_hist_device d,
         t_om_archive_hist_loc l,
         t_om_pod_info pi
where    c.cause                     = d.cause_of_trouble
and      pi.city                     is not null
and      pi.total_cust_cnt           > 0
and      pi.company                  = l.company
and      pi.distribution_location    = l.distribution_location_nbr
and      l.company                   = d.company
and      l.region_nbr                = d.region_nbr
and      l.outage_system             = d.outage_system
and      l.case_id                   = d.case_id
and      d.first_call_date_time     >= :start_date 
and      d.first_call_date_time     <= :end_date 
and      d.service_request_type      = 'LGTS'
and      d.cause_of_trouble not in
(select distinct cs.cause from t_om_cause_by_summary cs, t_om_cause_of_trouble c
where summary_cause = 'ERROR' and cs.cause = c.cause)
and      d.device_type              <> 'ERR'
and      d.total_duration_minutes   >= 60 * NVL(:hours_out,4)
and      d.total_duration_minutes   > 5
and      d.total_customers_affected >= NVL (:customers_out, 100)
and      to_char(d.region_nbr)      like :region_nbr 
group by d.region_nbr, pi.city, d.case_id, c.cause_desc, d.total_duration_minutes
/* having sum(total_cust_cnt) >= NVL (:customers_out, 100) */

order by d.region_nbr, pi.city, d.case_id
) 
group by region_nbr, city, cause
order by region_nbr, city, cause
) stats
where r.region = stats.region_nbr
)
```

Comment: What is mean `not works`? Throwing exception?

Comment: can we see where you are setting up your bind parameters in the .net code

Comment: eport.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("start_date", 
                StartDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("end_date",

Comment: EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("start_date", 
                StartDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("end_date",

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("hours_out", 
                hours_out, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("customers_out", 
                customers_out, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("region_nbr", 
                RegionDDL.SelectedValue, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("start_date", 
                StartDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("end_date", 
                EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("start_date", 
                StartDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("end_date", 
                EndDate.SelectedDate.Value, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("hours_out", 
                hours_out, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));
            Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("customers_out", 
                customers_out, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: Report.parameters.Add(index++, new OracleParameterHolder("region_nbr", 
                RegionDDL.SelectedValue, OracleParameterHolder.direction.Input));

Comment: please do not add code in the comments section, edit your question instead.

Comment: What are you setting `customers_out` to, and what values to you see for`sum(total_cust_cnt)` when that `having` clause is removed?

Comment: How do I read the value of the sum(total_cust_cnt) in VS13, the query is embed in a xml file